# How to sum + average of results from values taken from an array of values given by user

Tags: java, arrays

After adding 2 for loops – one to take values from user for rows and columns and another for print – I cannot figure out how to sum and give average after.

Write a program that allows a user to enter 5 results for each year of a 4 year course.
The app should:

Give an average for each year

Give a total average

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class YearlyResult {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //declare variables
    String[] year = {"Year 1","Year 2","Year 3","Year 4"};
    int rows = year.length;
    int numLectures = 5;
    int columns = numLectures;
    double sum;
    double[][] results;
    results = new double[rows][columns];

    //input
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            results[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter result "+(j+1)+"for"+year[i]));
        }
    }

    //output
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            System.out.println(year[i] + "  result #"+(j+1)+" is: " + results[i][j]);
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            sum = results[0][0];
            System.out.println("Total Yearly result" + sum*numLectures);
        }
        System.out.println("------------------");  
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
var sums = new double[results.length];
var avgs = new double[results.length];

for(var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
  for(var j=0; j < results[i].length; j++) {
    sums[i] = sums[i] + results[i][j];
   }
   avgs[i] = sums[i] / results[i].length;
}
```

This should (typed on mobile) should give you sum and average per row. The same way you can iterate over sums and avgs to get the overall values.

Would be much more elegant to use Java Stream API, but I think that’s beyond scope of this lesson.

Comment: I might be adding the suggestion to the wrong spot. I updated my output with the suggestion given and I get this result:(I entered the value 10 myself) Year 1  result #1 is: 10.0
Year 1  result #2 is: 10.0
Year 1  result #3 is: 10.0
Year 1  result #4 is: 10.0
Year 1  result #5 is: 10.0
test result[D@eafc191